# "Я - актриса", хочу тире, но контекст мешает; «Вот, мне платят 20 рублей, и я сегодня плохо играю» - запятая перед союзом?

Tags: пунктуация

> ...Я очень жадный до жизни человек. Хочу делать всё и сразу.
>   **Одновременно работаю на ста работах. В Театре Пушкина я актриса**. Там
>   совершенно отдельный мир и там нет места деньгам. Нельзя сказать:
>   **«Вот, мне платят 20 рублей, и я сегодня плохо играю».** Потому что люди,
>   которые на спектакль пришли именно сегодня, тебя таким запомнят и
>   таким «унесут». Поэтому каждый раз на сцене — предельный. **В то же
>   время я работаю на телевидении**, где совершенно другое сообщество, где
>   люди собираются вместе на двадцать минут в неделю, очень активно
>   общаются, что-то придумывают, генерируют, дальше расходятся каждый по
>   своему делу. Совершенно другая, модернизированная форма обмена
>   информацией между людьми.

Comment: После "вот"-то зачем запятая?

Comment: Интонация произносящего. Им же и воспроизведённая "на бумаге".

Comment: То есть это вводное слово, и что-то этой фразе предшествует? Если это частица, тут неоткуда взяться интонации.

Comment: Тёмыч, не учи жить: мы сайт торопимся к НГ открыть!

Comment: Да я ни в коем случае не претендую на поучения! Просто обсуждаю, разбираюсь. Если в подобной ситуации я ошибусь, "научит" тот, кто справедливо возразит. ;)

Comment: Тёмка, см. ответ гения Кати!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***В Театре Пушкина я актриса.*** —  Всё прекрасно, тире не нужно, правило об отсутствии тире после личных местоимений здесь работает идеально. Логическое ударение всегда подчёркивает слово АКТРИСА, завершающее предложение.

***«Вот, мне платят 20 рублей, и я сегодня плохо играю».*** —  Запятая после ВОТ обычно не ставится, но здесь она оправдана. Фраза произносится как МИМЕСИС (от греч. mimesis — подражание, воспроизведение), и ВОТ используется как вводное слово или как междометие —  выделяется интонацией.

Запятая перед союзом И нужна, ибо ВОТ относится только к первой части предложения. Ср.: ***Вот, раз мне платят 20 рублей, я плохо сегодня и играю.***

Comment: Катюша, Вы обратно гений! )))

Comment: ))) Просто выспалась наконец-то. Спасибо! С Новым годом!

Comment: Катюша, заходите почаще! Вы одна из очень немногих, кто понимает СРАЗУ, что переписывать/переделывать ничего не надо, надо выкручиваться с тем, что дано! Спасибо Вам!

Answer (score 0):

1. Одновременно я работаю на ста работах. В Театре Пушкина — актриса.
2. Вот — мне платят двадцать рублей, и я сегодня плохо играю.
3. В то же время, я работаю на телевидении, где совершенно другое сообщество.

Answer (score 0):

**Странное предложение** — по смыслу, структуре и пунктуации.

Я бы так написала: **Вот заплатИли мне 20 рублей, и я сегодня  играю плОхо**».

Платят — зарплата такая (при постоянной работе), а при чем тут тогда  "сегодня"? При постоянной работе я плохо играю, пока столько (очень мало) платят.

Другой вариант при непостоянной работе:  **Заплатили** сегодня  20 рублей (за разовый выход), поэтому плохо играю именно **сегодня**.

Comment: Да цифра с потолка взята! ))) Речь о человеке, пытающемся объять необъятное, и только ТЕАТР не позволяет кочевряжиться: за любые деньги работай на пределе возможностей.

Comment: Общий смысл понятен: платят мало - играю плохо. Заплатили мало (сегодня) - играю плохо (сегодня).Но предложение не соответствует этому смыслу. И запятая после ВОТ не у места, нет там паузы. (Обычно обособляются такие выражения: Ну вот, опять не успели). Там интонация выражает соответствие двух частей, то есть всего две фразы, куда же там еще частицу обособлять.

Comment: Я слышу это "вот" - констатация такая: во-от, назвался груздем, так и полезай...